# Web GL Rendering issue in Chrome 58

Tags: android, google-chrome, webgl

We have been using Web GL for one of our products and till the last update the app was working fine.

Since the last update the webgl render is pushed down to the bottom left corner and the scene is getting clipped to be only be visible in a small portion of the screen. we have no idea why this is happening and its is important that we get this fixed.

It would be a real help if some one can help us fix this issue so that it renders properly again.

It is working properly on desktop both mac and windows, on iphone is working fine. It is only present in chrome android version 58(Latest Update)

Attached below are the images, first one is the right render, and second one is wrong one.

Correct image

[image]

Problem image

[image]

Please Help

PS: we have tested this on Nexus 6

Comment: those look like CSS issues. Remove all the webgl and just set the canvas's background `canvas { background: red; }` and see if you get the same issue. Also are you setting the [document viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: it's not the css issue, we tried what you suggested but the same problem exists. for some reason the render is only the size as shown above. When we start zooming the scene the image comes into the small render region and it gets rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of the buffer memory in webgl for mobile devices, the line

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
antialias: true,
});
```

was the one causing the problem.

For mobile devices which can't handle the antialias, just use

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

This will solve the problem.